# #REF, #NAME errors in Getpivotdata Formula

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to get data from a Pivot table using formula,

```
=GETPIVOTDATA(A4:F12,$A$4,"Severity",$A$23,"Current Status",$C$20)
```

This code gives me a "#REF" Error and

```
=GETPIVOTDATA(Count of Issue Number,PivotTable1,"Severity",$A$23,"Current Status",$C$20)
```

This one gives a "#NAME" Error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose field names in quotes, and the second argument should be one cell within the pivot table:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Count of Issue Number",$A$4,"Severity",$A$23,"Current Status",$C$20)`

Comment: Hi, Its still not working. I have given both Name and a cell in pivot table as second argument. When I give name, it shows #NAME and for the cell, its showing #REF.

Comment: I've just edited my answer - the second argument was incorrect before.

Comment: Hi, I copied the Row and column headings from Pivot Table to the new table as row and column headings where I used the GETPIVOTDATA. And now its working. Is there anything related to format of cells or something?

Comment: They need to match - if the pivot field contains text, then your criterion field should be text.

Comment: Now here is another problem,
Can't we take data from Pivot Table for multiple tables using GETPIVOTDATA? I created a Pivot Table with 3 fields in Row and tried to capture each 3 of them in 3 different tables using GETPIVOTDATA. But only first table is capturing the values.

Comment: Yes you can do that. It's impossible for me to say why it isn't working with nothing to go on. Also, this is nothing to do with the original question, which I believe is solved.